# Can I express the numbers at more than one decimal point using 成?

Tags: word, number

I know that if you want to express "X-tenth(s)", you can use 成. For example:

> 增产三成
>
> 上座率有九成。

However, these only express the figure at one decimal point. If you want to express any figure at two or more decimal points, can you still use 成? For example:

> 黄金周五成北京市民选择的是4至6天的行程。 # one-decimal point (0.5)
>
> 黄金周五十五成北京市民选择的是4至6天的行程。 # two-decimal points (0.55)

Or if you can't, how can you express the figure usually?

Comment: ０。５５：零点五五， ５５％:百分之五十五，seems to exhaust possibilities, see grammars on numerals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could say 五成五 for 0.55 or 55%. 99% could be 九成九.

For example, 九成九的人会参加这会议, meaning 99% of people will attend the meeting.

Usually, people won't put that accurate. They may just say 大约五成, meaning 50% or so. But 几成几 is a normal expression.

Comment: Thanks. So how about three decimal points (e.g. 0.938)?

Comment: No one would use three decimal points for this kind of purpose. To be more precise, you might have to use percentage or just 0.xxxxx.

Comment: OK, then in that case is the expression always in arabic numerals? Or can you also express it in Chinese characters?

Comment: Or, you could joke on it by saying 九成三点八 for 0.938. lol. People would understand you。

Comment: xxx成xxx is usually written in Chinese characters in the former register. eg.  九成九, 五成五, ... ...

Comment: I meant in the case of three decimal points. For example can you express 0.921 in Chinese characters?

Comment: It would look awkward when 0.921 written in Chinese characters.

Comment: I won't understand 九成三点八 ....

Comment: BTW do you usually express 62% as 六成二? Or express it in other ways? What is the most common form?

Comment: @Blaszard, 几成几 is not used to replace the percentage. People usually use it for a rough estimation. I would think 几成 is more like 'xxx out of ten' in English. let's say 六成->6 out of ten. Normally, we just say xxx成 and xxx成xxx is not often used, because you don't have to be that accurate in general. In formal registers, we use percentage, like in news articles, reports and etc. xxx成 is a colloquial term.

Comment: @fefe: that's just a joke, which I'd heard it before.

Comment: Ah, OK thanks. The sentence above is from a news article on 人民网, FYI.

Comment: 黄金周五成北京市民选择的是4至6天的行程。It's not that serious for this kind of reports. This kind of report is just to give some information to citizens and unnecessary to address seriously.